# web extension ajax dont work on crossdomain call

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I tried to do a request to wikipedia from the content_script in a web extension, but it didn't work for me.
The console dont show me any information about it. Can I have some permission problems? or maybe it just problems with my knowledge about it.
Here is my code:
Manifest:

```
     {
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "SearchH1Extension",
      "version": "1.0", 
      "description": "Toma todas los tags h1 de un dom particular, los agrupa y busca en wikipedia los titulos realcionados con esas palabras",

      "icons": {
        "48": "resources/icons/border-48.png"
      },

      "permissions": [
        "activeTab","tabs","http://*/*","https://*/*"        
      ],

      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "resources/icons/beasts-32.png",
        "theme_icons": [{
            "light": "resources/icons/beasts-32-light.png",
            "dark": "resources/icons/beasts-32.png",
            "size": 32
        }],

        "default_title": "SearchH1",
        "default_popup": "popup/searchH1Popup.html"
      },     

      "background": {
          "scripts": ["background/searchBackground.js"]
      },

      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["*://*.com.ar/*","*://*.com/*"],
          "js": [
            "content_scripts/searchContentScript.js",
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

content_scripts/searchContentScript.js:

```
(function() {
    function searchH1() {
        console.log("here I come to show this message...")

        /*None of the 3 calls by ajax prints on the console*/   

        //FIRST CALL WITHOUT JQUERY  (wantto return all the page wiki)
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php', false); 
        req.send(null);
        if (req.status == 200)
            dump(req.responseText);       

        //SECOND CALL WITH JQUERY
        /*example from wikipedia api */
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
            data: {
                    format: "json",
                    action: "parse",
                    page: "FIFA",
                    prop: "text",
                    section: 0,
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            headers: {
                    'Api-User-Agent': 'MyCoolTool/1.1 (http://example.com/MyCoolTool/; MyCoolTool@example.com) BasedOnSuperLib/1.4'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)   
                    return data;            
            }
        });

        //THIRD CALL BASIC AJAX GET  
        $.get('https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=FIFA', function( data ) {          
            console.log(data);
        });
    }


    browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {     
        searchH1(); 
    })

    })();
```

Comment: `$.ajax` in a web extension? how can you be sure jquery is available to you? `dump(req.responseText);` ... what is this `dump` business?

Comment: have a look at https://pastebin.com/bgDy52wp ... there's the asynchronous version of your XHR code, and also `fetch` version - see if either of those two work out for you

Comment: I dont know how, but this way work for me.. Maybe is the asynchronous call that was happen  athx!